# Preventing adding up of colors for multiple brush strokes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, brush

This is somewhat a newbie question, but I couldn't find any solution.
While painting, if I lift up the brush and start painting again, colors start adding up at intersections. This makes it hard to make it look smooth. As you see in the image it is darker in the place where two brush strokes intersect.

The behavior I want is, as if brush is not lifted, painting over the same area will not change the color unless it is darker (Max filter maybe?). Or maybe I should change the way I work. What do you suggest?

[image: Photoshop brush strokes adding up]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! To get the most out of the site, please review [our help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). What program are you using to paint? What are your brush settings? And what have you tried to do to stop the paint overlap?

Answer (score 3):

Next to the opacity is a drop down box labeled "mode:" change that to 'normal'.

Answer (score 1):

The brush has opacity (transparency), so for example is you paint 2 lines of opacity 20% one on top of the other you get a 40% opacity area.
Change the brush opacity to 100%:
[image]

Comment: The problem is, I want opacity to not increase even if I painted over. You suggest me to increase it all the way up to %100.

Comment: Draw everything with 100% opacity on an empty layer and then change the opacity of the entire layer. If you need explanation on how to do that ask and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well but, I don't want everything to be at same opacity. I am using a graphic tablet and colors should have different opacity according to pressure I apply.

Comment: Well that's how opacity works. Opacity means transparency or see-through, or see through the object to whats underneath it. If I understand correctly you want a white tint to your final colour. You can add a white colour overlay effect to the entire layer to get that

Comment: You are not understanding. I am trying to do digital painting. Digital painting consists of continuous colors instead of 1-2 discrete colors. To paint a shadowy area I apply more pressure than normal to give more opacity. But If I lift up my brush to draw another shadow area, at the intersection of areas, my problem occurs.

Comment: @SirKurt Naty is right in how opacity works. You're trying to use opacity in a way it is not meant to be used. I think this video will help you out in figuring out your brush settings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2atrW3xozM

Comment: The video shows very basics. I know how opacity works. That is why I am asking for a workaround. I have seen pro illustrators express brightness value like this using opacity so I think it is also meant to be used like this (The question is not about why I use it though).

Comment: @SirKurt at 2:04 in the video, is that not what you're trying to achieve? The brush is painting at different opacity of white (light levels of that color) depending on the pen pressure.

Comment: The problem is that the stroking system does not have enough memory to implement your request. Once the stroke is finalized it gets committed to the buffer, and it cant differentiate rhe states. @SirKurt I was able to make a blendng mode that would do what you ask experimenttally in a test software. Unfortunately its side effects were so unintuitive that i just abandoned this train of tought.

Comment: Basically what you want, can not be done using Photoshop. It is just not how it works. The solution to your problem should be that you adapt your workflow according to how the program works. Most people who use Photoshop for digital painting can work just fine with it the way it works. Any real life color (water colors etc.) would behave just the same. If you paint over the same sport twice it adds up.

Comment: @SirKurt, Naty is 100% right here. Just change the layer's opacity, not the brush's opacity. If you're using tablet pressure to determine opacity, instead use the pressure to determine color and then lower the overall opacity and it will create the same effect without causing the issue you're mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Have the brush at 100% opacity and lower the opacity of the layer you are shading on.

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen pro illustrators express brightness value like this using opacity so I think it is also meant to be used like this (The question is not about why I use it though).

Most videos of pro illustrators I've seen either (a) paint at 70% - 100% opacity most of the time without using the pressure sensitivy and have the magical ability to always pick exactly the right color before their next stroke, or (b) paint at around to 70% - 100% opacity and make use of the pressure sensitivity to mix their next color, then pick from their color blend area the color they want to use for their next stroke.

So if doing something like what is shown in your image the typical painter I've seen would have done that first stroke with 30% opacity black. Then hold alt and click the color to pick up exactly that shade of grey. Then undo. Then change brush opacity to 70% or higher then paint with near-opaque grey instead of near-transparent black which is what your image shows.